# Using multiple IF ELSE in A multi-statement TVF Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, sql-function

How can I use IF ELSE statements inside A multi-statement TVF ? My Cide goes like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION Production.ms_tvf_ProductCostDifference
(
@ID INT ,

)
     RETURNS @retCostDifference TABLE
     (
      ProductId INT ,
      CostDifference MONEY
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

    With ABC as 
     ( Select ------
     )
    if @ID ='1'
    //some code using ABC defined
    ELSe IF @ID=2
    //Somecode
    Return;
    END
```

How should be the flow?

Comment: I am getting some sytax errors.. on IF and insert statements

Comment: Update the question, don't add important information in comments

Comment: As for the question itself - just check the syntax. Googling for "T-SQL IF" returns it in the very first result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use `IF` inside a `WITH`

instead you need something like this

```
  if @ID ='1'
    With ABC as 
         ( Select ------
         )
        //some code using ABC defined
  ELSE IF @ID=2
      With ABC as 
         ( Select ------
         )
      //Somecode
  Return;
```